# What's the proper format for a union initializer list?

Tags: c++, c, initialization, unions

Say I have a class/struct with a single union in it... something like:

```
struct Box { union { AS128 intr; struct { AS32 a, b, c, d; }; }; };
```

What's the proper way to do an initializer list for this kind of data type?

```
Box iMyBoxA = { 10, 10, 100, 100 };
Box iMyBoxB = ( Box ){ 10, 10, 100, 100 };
```

The 'A' option above works in many cases, but isn't completely portable... giving the error "no known conversion for argument 1 from 'brace-enclosed initializer list'".  And the second doesn't compile with "Cannot omit braces around initialization of subobject..."

I've tried a few other cases and can't seem to get it to compile across multiple platforms.

Comment: You have five separate members in your union. You can only use one, but you give four initializers.

Comment: This question is silly, initialize one by may.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? Can we use C99 designated initializers?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161008/union-initialisation

Comment: Why would a union have four members of the same type? Are `a, b, c, d` supposed to be members of a structure nested in the union?

Comment: Whoops!  Yeah, sorry... I mis-typed that.  The question is updated.

Comment: Jonathan's answer below actually covered the case I really meant to ask about... so no worries.  Sorry for the confusion though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original version of the structure and union definition in the question was:

```
struct Box { union { AS128 intr; AS32 a, b, c, d; } };
```

This is a little unusual.  Assuming the types AS128 and AS32 are defined, then it is equivalent to:

```
struct Box1  // Renamed for convenience of testing
{
    union
    {
        AS128 intr;
        AS32  a;
        AS32  b;
        AS32  c;
        AS32  d;
    };
};
```

That is, it is a union of an `AS128` called `intr` and 4 separate values of type `AS32` called `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` (with the latter 4 all occupying the same space).

Presumably, what you have in mind is:

```
struct Box2
{
    union
    {
        AS128 intr;
        struct
        {
            AS32  a;
            AS32  b;
            AS32  c;
            AS32  d;
        } s;
    };
};
```

This uses the anonymous members feature of C11 (listed in the Foreword of ISO/IEC 9899:2011 as a new feature compared to C99).  *[The question has now been fixed to reflect more or less this notation (using an anonymous structure).  Note that you can't directly designate an anonymous union member, so the `s` above is a good idea, at least.  The structure without the `s` can be used, but I don't think you can initialize the structure unless you can designate it — you can only designate named elements of a union.]*

With the first variant (`struct Box1`), you can initialize the first member (the `AS128 intr;` member) with no name:

```
struct Box1 b1 = { { 1234 } };
```

The outer braces are for the structure; the inner braces are for the (anonymous) union.

Or you can specify which member to initialize using a designated initializer:

```
struct Box1 b2 = { { .a = 1234 } };
```

Note that you can't do:

```
struct Box1 b3 = { { .a = 1234, .b = 2341 } };
```

The compiler gives a warning (see the example code below).

With the second variant (`struct Box2`), with the nested structure, you can still use the undesignated initializer or the designated initializers, but this time, you could specify all 4 of the members of the structure:

```
struct Box2 b4 = { { .s = { .a = 32, .b = 65, .c = 48, .d = 97 } } };
```

#### Example code

Using funny types for the `AS128` and `AS32` type names.

```
typedef long AS128;
typedef char AS32;

struct Box1
{
    union
    {
        AS128 intr;
        AS32  a;
        AS32  b;
        AS32  c;
        AS32  d;
    };
};

struct Box2
{
    union
    {
        AS128 intr;
        struct
        {
            AS32  a;
            AS32  b;
            AS32  c;
            AS32  d;
        } s;
    };
};

struct Box1 b1a = { { 1234 } };
struct Box1 b1b = { { .intr = 1234 } };
struct Box1 b1c = { { .a = 32 } };
//struct Box1 b1d = { { .b = 29, .c = 31 } }; // Invalid double initialization
//error: initialized field overwritten [-Werror=override-init]

struct Box2 b2a = { { 1234 } };
struct Box2 b2b = { { .intr = 1234 } };
struct Box2 b2c = { { .s = { .a = 29, .b = 30, .c = 31, .d = 32 } } };
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply!  And you actually fixed my mis-type already... I meant to ask about your 'Box2' example.  Let me give this a shot.

Comment: Nice!  Your last example is exactly what I wanted.  Thanks.  :)

Comment: Actually... one last question.  Is there no way to leave off the name for the internal struct?  I'd really prefer something like `struct Box2 b2d = { { 29, 30, 31, 32 } };` so that I don't have to refer to `b2d.a` as `b2d.s.a`.

Comment: The unnamed initializers would work as long as you designate the structure: `struct Box2 b2d = { { .s = { 29, 30, 31, 32 } } };`. Or you could place the structure ahead of `intr` so it was the first member of the union, and then you'd write: `struct Box2a b2d = { { { 29, 30, 31, 32 } } };`.  I've not verified this with the compiler, but I believe it is true.

Comment: Note my new commentary about naming the structure element in the union so that you can designate it for initialization; I wasn't able to initialize an anonymous element of a union — but I may not have spent enough time working through the compiler error messages.

Comment: Ah, good point... the order might actually be relevant. I'll give that a try.

Comment: Yeah, you got it!  Moving the struct to the first member in the union and using the triple-bracket approach seems to be working.  Thanks again, that's just what I've been looking for.

Answer (score 4):

A union holds only one member at a time, so you initialize it with only one value.

You may use `Box iMyBoxA = { value };` to initialize the first-listed member of the union or `Box iMyBoxA = { .name = value };` to initialize a particular member by name.

Some notes:

Your code is missing a semicolon after the union declaration; it should be:

```
struct Box { union { AS128 intr; AS32 a, b, c, d; }; };
```

Since you have a union inside a struct, you ought to use two sets of braces for the initializers:

```
Box iMyBoxA = { { value } };
```

The syntax with one set of braces is permitted but may elicit warnings from your compiler.

Designated initializers (member names in initializers) are a C 1999 feature. This question is tagged with C and C++. A C++ compiler might or might not accept a designated initializer. In C, you would also need to declare `Box` as a type using `typedef` or change `Box iMyBoxA…` to `struct Box iMyBoxA…`.

In C, anonymous unions are new in C 2011.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... although I actually mis-typed something in my question.  Please give another look and see if it makes more sense.  Thanks.